# How to only use stable versions of dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have two question about Android Studio Gradle dependencies:

1) Is there a way to have Android Studio only suggest the latest stable versions of Gradle dependencies instead of alpha and beta versions? If not, how do I efficiently find that for myself?

For example:

When using Room in my apps, I follow the instructions here to add all the dependencies:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room

The sidebar that shows all the versions goes from version 2.0.0-beta01 to version 2.1.0-alpha01. Does this mean that there was never a stable release of version 2.0.0 and that the last stable release was the pre-androidx version 1.1.1 released almost a year ago?

2) How unsafe are these alpha and beta versions? Can they significantly break code?

Comment: "Is there a way to have Android Studio only suggest the latest stable versions of Gradle dependencies instead of alpha and beta versions?" -- where are you getting the suggestions? In the Gradle file editor, I only get suggestions of alpha/beta versions if I already specified an alpha/beta version. "Does this mean that there was never a stable release of version 2.0.0" -- there are several Room artifacts, and certainly some have a 2.0.0, as you can see [in the Maven repo index](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html).

Comment: "How unsafe are these alpha and beta versions?" -- at Google I|O 2019, in the Android fireside chat, Yiğit Boyar said that beta versions are pretty good... but, of course, he is responsible for them... :-)

Comment: This question does not deserve to be downvoted. Regularly, I get suggestions for alpha versions for some libraries when I am working with a stable version. Not a real problem, but somewhat annoying.

Comment: Hello @gentlemanRabbit did my answer help you in understanding the differnces between alpha and beta? Also how to get only stable versions?

Answer (score -1):

**1.)**

You can change that following the steps below:

Go `File` > `Settings` > `Appearance & Behavior` > `System Settings` > `Updates` > `[✓] Automatically check updatesfor [Stable Channel]` > `Apply` > `OK`

[image: Stable Channel]

---

**2.)**

**Alpha**

- Alpha releases are functionally stable, but may not be
  feature-complete.
- While a release is in alpha, APIs may be added, removed, or changed.

**Beta**

- Beta releases are functionally stable and have a feature-complete API
  surface.
- They are ready for production use but may contain bugs.
- A beta release cannot use experimental compiler features (such as
  `@UseExperimental`).
- Dependencies on other libraries must be beta, rc, or stable versions.
  No alpha dependencies are allowed.